# NFePHP: Gerar XML de nota fiscal modelo 20

Tags: php, xml, nfe

Preciso gerar o XML de nota fiscal de serviço prestado (NFS-e) modelo 20.

olhando a documentação do NFePHP, constatei que ele gera o XML porém no modelo 55 que é a nota fiscal de venda de produtos.

Alguém sabe se o NFePHP gera a nota fiscal no modelo 20? ou se existe outro projeto em PHP para gerar a nota fiscal no modelo 20?

Comment: Já tentou pesquisar no [group do NFePHP](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nfephp) ?

Comment: @gmsantos sim já procurei lá mas infelizmente não achei nada.

Comment: @guilherme, NFS-e é um projeto diferente de NFe, os webservices são outros, cada município faz de uma forma diferente a implementação. Aconselho você procurar um componente especifico para NFS-e. Não é somente o modelo que muda.